# Sourcetree: accessing two repos, one with a key pair and another with a password

Tags: git, macos, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to give access to a developer to our private git repo. He is using Sourcetree on a Mac, and I told him to configure it in the exact same way than I did:

1. In Sourcetree, go to "Repository / Repository Settings".
2. Add a new remote, with `ssh://(username)@our.host.name/our/path` as URL.

And just type in the password whenever it asked him to.

(It's been so long since I set it up that I honestly don't remember how I did it in my own Mac, whether I typed in the password in Sourcetree or I had to open a Terminal or whatever. My point is, though, that in my Mac this works perfectly: I don't have any accounts set up in my Sourcetree, nor I have used it to generate any keys: I just have a repo with an URL in the form of "ssh://username@host", and it just works).

Anyway, he did that, and after fumbling a bit, he can clone the repo and pull from Sourcetree without problems, but whenever he tries to push to the repo , he gets an error message saying he couldn't connect, and the server logs say:

```
Jan 24 17:52:34 vps sshd[23088]: Failed publickey for [username]
Jan 24 17:52:34 vps sshd[23088]: Failed none for [username]
Jan 24 17:52:34 vps sshd[23088]: Failed password for [username]
Jan 24 17:52:34 vps sshd[23088]: Failed password for [username]
```

If he opens a Terminal and pushes using git from the command line, he can do so: the system prompts him for a password, he types it, and that's it.

I asked to see his `.ssh/` directory, and he had in it a `config` file that said this:

```
# --- SourceTree generated

Host [username]-Github
  HostName github.com
  Username [username]
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile /Users/em/.ssh/[username]-Github
  UseKeyChain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

And a public/private key pair for Github.

In other words, he uses Sourcetree with a public/private key pair to access Github.

So, the obvious thing to do would be to create a public/private key pair for our own server, but at this point I have my doubts: how do I make Sourcetree know which key to use for Github and which for our server? Do I edit the config file by hand? Which syntax do I use to make it know which repository I am referring to?

According to [this link](https://www.danclarke.com/multiple-ssh-keys-for-git), Sourcetree doesn't actually  use SSH's config file... and yet our copy says "Sourcetree generated". On the other hand, that link is actually for Sourcetree on Windows. I've found almost no documentation for our case online (Sourcetree on Mac, two repositories, using different keys for each).

Comment: If it be some help, go through https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-additional-ssh-keys-271943168.html

Comment: Thanks. I saw that link, but it doesn't actually explain my case: it's only about setting things up with Mercurial and Bitbucket Cloud.

Comment: It has a section "Set up additional SSH keys for Git" - The documentation tells to setup using **`ssh-add ~/.ssh/<username>`**

Comment: Okay, but how do I tell Sourcetree to use that key and not the other one for my git repo?